# How to solve error with get() when using <- operator?

Tags: r

I'm triying to change the class of a column in a df, but this is inside a big for loop. Then I have to call the name of the columns in the df with paste0. My code is:

```
get(paste0(Pathways$KEGG[1]," ",Pathways$PATHWAY[1]))$Kegg_Data<-
as.character(get(paste0(Pathways$KEGG[1]," ",Pathways$PATHWAY[1]))$Kegg_Data)
```

and i get the error: could not find function "get<-"
Running this:
`get(paste0(Pathways$KEGG[1]," ",Pathways$PATHWAY[1]))$Kegg_Data`
or this:
`as.character(get(paste0(Pathways$KEGG[1]," ",Pathways$PATHWAY[1]))$Kegg_Data)`
alone work perfectly!!

Maybe i should rewrite with %<% intead <- , but i don't know how to do that.
Thank you.

Edit 1: a MRE as suggested:

1. 3 dfs with my data that have the same content but, different names
   (i have a variable number of df in real data, lets say 15)

```
# A df : 3 × 2         # A df : 3 × 2         # A df : 3 × 2
# name= "1 mtcars"     # name= "3 motos"    #name= "74 yates"
      X      Kegg_data      X     Kegg_data       X      Kegg_data
   <factor>  <factor>    <factor>  <factor>    <factor>  <factor>
 1   123      qwe      1   123      qwe       1   123      qwe
 2   456      asd      2   456      asd       2   456      asd
 3   789      zxc      3   789      zxc       3   789      zxc
```

2. the df that contain the name of my others df.

```
# A df (name= dfnames): 3 × 2
   digit   letters    
   <chr>  <chr> 
 1  1     mtcars      
 2  3     motos   
 3  74    yates
```

2. now, i want to automate changing the class of the column Kegg_Data of each df to "chr"

```
for(j in seq_along(dfnames$digit)){
get(paste0(dfnames$digit[j]," ",dfnames$letters[j]))$Kegg_Data<-
as.character(get(paste0(dfnames$digit[j]," ",dfnames$letters[j]))$Kegg_Data)}
```

In other words, my problem is calling the name of the df as:

```
get(paste0(dfnames$digit[j]," ",dfnames$letters[j]))
```

or as:

```
paste0(dfnames$digit[j]," ",dfnames$letters[j])
```

isn't compatible with " <- "

Comment: I am 100% certain there are easier/better/more robust ways of doing this, but a *minimal, reproducible example* would make it easier to show you how...

Comment: @Limey I added a MRE as suggested, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.  Here are some.  Your reference to `%<%` makes me think you're open to the tidyverse, so I'll include some options for that.  You've not given us any test data, so I'm using `mtcars` as an example.  I've converted it to a `tibble` simply for ease of formatting.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- as_tibble(mtcars)

# All at once
df %>%  mutate(across(everything(), as.character))

#One column at a time [1]
df %>%  mutate(across(c("mpg"), as.character))

#One column at a time [2]
df[["mpg"]] <- as.character(df[["mpg"]])  
df

# A selection of columns [1]
df %>%  mutate(across(c("mpg", "cyl"), as.character))

# A selection of columns [2]
for (col in c("mpg", "cyl")) {
  df[[col]] <- as.character(df[[col]])  
}
df
```

giving, for example,

```
# A tibble: 32 × 11
   mpg   cyl    disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 21    6      160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
 2 21    6      160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
 3 22.8  4      108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
 4 21.4  6      258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
 5 18.7  8      360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
 6 18.1  6      225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
 7 14.3  8      360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
 8 24.4  4      147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
 9 22.8  4      141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
10 19.2  6      168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
# … with 22 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

*Edit in response to OP's comment*

"the problem here is that the name of my df is a string that i need to get from a file": Wow!  I admit I don't have a complete picture of your workflow, but I find it difficult to imagine a more awkward approach.

My first observation is that `print(variable) %>% ...` simply will not work.  Your are confusing the textual representation of the value of an object with the object itself.

IMHO, your approach should be to obtain the data frame "pointed to" by your text variable and store it in an object whose name is known to you.  Do this at the earliest possible opportunity.  Ideally, you should design your workflow so that you never have to do this.  But, as I said, I don't know enough asbout your workflow to be able suggest a sensible solution.

Given what you have said, my approach would be similar to the following.  (This is untested code.)

```
for (dfName in nameOfDF$letters) {
  df <- get(dfName)
  # Remainder of workflow, referencing df.  eg...
  df[["mpg"]] <- as.character(df[["mpg"]])
}
```

There are many, many tutorials on the web that will give you a good grounding in R basics.  Please study them before proceeding any further with your workflow.

Comment: When i use: 

paste0(Pathways$KEGG[1]," ",Pathways$PATHWAY[1]) %>%  mutate(across(c("Kegg_Data"), as.character))


I get:
Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: That is expected.  `mutate` works on the data frame, not the column. Look at how I use it in the examples above.

Comment: the problem here is that the name of my df is a string that i need to get from a file

Comment: Thank you @Limey !!! with that last code i solved it, first making a new column with the name of the df (so i don't have to use paste0 to generate it every time from 2 columns)! then i proceeded as usual and using your approach!